# How does Visual Studio SSIS Handle Extensions and Package Deployment?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, package, visual-studio-extensions

I'm fairly new to Visual Studio and SSIS and was wondering if someone could just clear up for me how Visual Studio SSIS Projects and Visual Studio in general handle Add-In Extension and Package Deployment.

The Scenario: I am currently developing and creating a Visual Studio SSIS Package on my local machine.I need to use an extension from the Tools > Extensions and Updates which just links me to a webpage.I need to  install this and use it to make a package which I will deploy to the Integration Services Catalog on a SQL Server 2014 that does not have Visual Studio installed. When I deploy this project as a package will the things the extension did be baked into the package or is it like references where I will need to install the extension on the server that will be running the package via SQL Agent Job. Thanks, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deploy a package to the catalog, all libraries/extensions (eg.azure  connection etc) are deployed along-with, so no special treatment is needed. But many a times you will need to ensure your frameworks( eg. .net 4.0 etc) exist for the extension to be executed on the integration services server you are deploying to.

In some cases you have to register the dlls using GACUtil, to the integration services server. Your custom tool installation instructions will specify that.

Comment: Thank you. Just what I wanted to know.